# Making a dynamic array that accepts any type in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to find a way to make a struct to hold a dynamic array that can work with any data type (Including user defined data types), so far this is what I came up with.

```
#define Vector(DATATYPE) struct {   DATATYPE* data; size_t size; size_t used; }

typedef Vector(int) int_Vector;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int_Vector vec;
    return 0;
}
```

While this works I was wondering, is this good practice? Should I be doing something like this or is there a better method? Also is there a method to implement this with out the `typedef Vector(int) int_vector` part. Basically a way that would enable me to use the array the same way c++ uses templates where it would look something like this:

```
#define Vector(DATATYPE) struct {   DATATYPE* data; size_t size; size_t used; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Vector(int) vec;
    return 0;
}
```

Mainly to avoid so many typedefs and have it all under one name.

Comment: There are various ways of doing this, frankly none of them particularly clean. Another trick is to store the data as a flexible array member and have the vector interface pass and return the address of the first data element, via implicitly cast void pointers. Yet another is to use X-macros to generate entire type-specific interfaces for type safety.

Comment: Not an answer, but the FreeBSD guys heavily rely on macros to obtain the behaviour you seek in [sys/queue.h](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/queue.h)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well no, C doesn't have a template system so you can't use one.

You can mimic the effects with macros like you did (pretty clever solution) but that's of course a bit non-standard and requires users of your code to learn the macro and its limitations.

Normally C code doesn't try, since it's so awkward.

The most "generic" typical vector is something like glib's [`GArray`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html), but that doesn't pretend to know the type of each element. Instead that is left to the user to care about when accessing, and the array just models each element as being `n` bytes.

There's `_Generic()` in C11 which might help a bit, I'm honestly not very experienced in that.

Comment: @zee gcc has been supporting C11 for a long time.

Comment: @2501 Not entirely everything, it supports the majority of it but there are still parts that aren't implemented such as threads.

Comment: @zee gcc has a valid, conforming,  C11 implementation. The library threads.h is is conditional feature.

Comment: @unwind Maybe you can add a reference to the linux kernels implementation of lists. It is not exactly what OP tries to do but I find it rather clever and it works with any struct.

Comment: @2501 huh TIL, thanks for the info. Still leaves the vs compiler though. I'm not sure however which I should use now. As far as I know from some forum threads I read is that using c99 is mostly better for comparability as just about every single compiler, however as we've seen I'm not as familiar with the standards and which compilers fully implement what as you peeps. So is there any reason to actually use c99 right now or should I just switch to c11?

Comment: @zee If on windows use MinGW-w64 and gcc/clang.

Answer (score 6):

The second example won't work because the two variable are defined as distinct types even though their members are the same. Why is this so, is covered in my [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858240/how-to-return-an-anonymous-struct-in-c/27858651#27858651).

However the syntax can be kept the same using a slightly different approach:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define vector(type)    struct vector_##type

struct vector_int
{
    int* array;
    size_t count;
} ;

int main(void)
{
    vector(int) one = { 0 };
    vector(int) two = { 0 };

    one = two;
    ( void )one ;

    return 0;
}
```

The usage surprisingly similar to C++'s `vector<int>` and a full example can be seen here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define vector_var(type)    struct vector_##type

struct vector_int
{
    int* array;
    size_t count;
};

void vector_int_Push( struct vector_int* object , int value ) 
{
    //implement it here
}

int vector_int_Pop( struct vector_int* object ) 
{
    //implement it here
    return 0;
}    

struct vector_int_table
{
    void( *Push )( struct vector_int* , int );
    int( *Pop )( struct vector_int* );

} vector_int_table = { 
                         .Push = vector_int_Push ,
                         .Pop = vector_int_Pop 
                     };

#define vector(type)   vector_##type##_table

int main(void)
{
    vector_var(int) one = { 0 };
    vector_var(int) two = { 0 };

    one = two;

    vector(int).Push( &one , 1 );
    int value = vector(int).Pop( &one );
    ( void )value;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The trick is to make all of the interface functions macros which unpack the structure. A common header structure helps but it does get a bit messy.

Comment: @doynax Yes I'm hesitant to use: `vector(int).Push`, over simply prefixing the function name and call the actual function directly: `vector_int_Push`.

Comment: It can be made to work, think `#define vector_push(p, v) (*vector_push_(&(p)->common_header) = *(v))`, but it gets messy unless you can rely compatible void pointers or _Generic to update the pointer field. The flexible array member version is cleaner though, especially if you use and `int *` type with the header at a negative offset. Anyway, if you are going to go the explicitly typed route then consider using `X-macros` to generate the interface functions.

Comment: @zee Post your code into ideone.com and make sure it works first.

Comment: @2501 thanks will do in just a sec!


Edit: Here's the code! http://ideone.com/l3ZDqw

Using this method it seems like I can get what I wanted from the original question!

Comment: @zee That won't work: https://ideone.com/t0J8Sl My first example does this correctly and without typedefs.

Comment: @2501 that's strange, it compiled on my machine (mingw on win10) and when I pressed execute on the website it ran just fine as well.

Comment: @zee That because you didn't click on my link.

Comment: @2501 ah sorry I didn't see that last bit that you added, I'm currently working on it. I'll see if I can find something to bypass that issue if I do I'll update the op or edit this comment :)

Comment: @zee My first example does exactly that.

Comment: @2501 I realize that and it's very clever but I want to see if it's possible to have the macro define everything in a way where I wouldn't have to define any structs. Because as it stands right now if I (or a user) want to add a user-defined type (struct) it's not possible to do that without going into the header file where the dynamic array implementation is and defining the struct there. It's not the most important thing to do but it's just a fun to try and see if I can figure it if not your solution is definitely a very good as well :)

Answer (score 5):

`Vector(DATATYPE) struct {   DATATYPE* data; size_t size; size_t used; }` also fails for pointers to functions.

`void*` is sufficient and well defined for a pointer to any *object*, but not so for a pointer to a function.

C does allow a pointer to a function of one type to be saved as a pointer to a function of another type.  By using a `union` of the two below, code has enough space for saving the pointer to any type.  The management of what type and what member used remains open.

```
union u_ptr {
  void *object;
  void (*function)();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not bad. And I don't see any disadvantage.
Just to explain another method, mostly common used in this case use union:

```
typedef union { int i; long l; float f; double d; /*(and so on)*/} vdata;
typedef enum  {INT_T,LONG_T,FLOAT_T, /*(and so on)*/} vtype;
typedef struct 
{
    vtype t;
    vdata data
} vtoken;
typedef struct
{
    vtoken *tk;
    size_t sz;
   size_t n;
} Vector;
```

So this is possible way. The enum of datatype, you can avoid with typedefs, but if you use mixed (ex: sum long, to double, to float and so on) you must use them, since int + double is not equal to double+int; This is also a reason, because is more easy to see unions do this job. You leave al the arithmetic rules untouched.

Comment: The disadvantage with this kind of union-based "variant" is that an item can never be smaller than the largest possible type. So when the user adds "bombastic_gigabyte_t" (for which he actually just needs 1 single instance), it will make _all_ instances of your variant that big, then blow out all RAM memory in your computer. Which makes unions a bad idea for this kind of generic programming.

Comment: @Lundin So model `bombastic_gigabyte_t` as a list of `fantastic_word_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245994/584518) regarding a polymorphism solution, we can as well make it include pointer types or user-defined types. The major advantage with this method is to get rid of the "data type" enum and with it all the run-time checking switch statements.

**variant.h**

```
#ifndef VARIANT_H
#define VARIANT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef void print_data_t (const void* data);
typedef void print_type_t (void);

typedef struct 
{
  void* data;
  print_data_t* print_data;
  print_type_t* print_type;
} variant_t;

void print_data_char    (const void* data);
void print_data_short   (const void* data);
void print_data_int     (const void* data);
void print_data_ptr     (const void* data);
void print_data_nothing (const void* data);

void print_type_char        (void);
void print_type_short       (void);
void print_type_int         (void);
void print_type_int_p       (void);
void print_type_void_p      (void);
void print_type_void_f_void (void);

void print_data (const variant_t* var);
void print_type (const variant_t* var);

#define variant_init(var) {                \
  .data = &var,                            \
                                           \
  .print_data = _Generic((var),            \
    char:  print_data_char,                \
    short: print_data_short,               \
    int:   print_data_int,                 \
    int*:  print_data_ptr,                 \
    void*: print_data_ptr,                 \
    void(*)(void): print_data_nothing),    \
                                           \
  .print_type = _Generic((var),            \
    char:  print_type_char,                \
    short: print_type_short,               \
    int:   print_type_int,                 \
    int*:  print_type_int_p,               \
    void*: print_type_void_p,              \
    void(*)(void): print_type_void_f_void) \
}


#endif /* VARIANT_H */
```

**variant.c**

```
#include "variant.h"

void print_data_char    (const void* data) { printf("%c",  *(const char*)  data); }
void print_data_short   (const void* data) { printf("%hd", *(const short*) data); }
void print_data_int     (const void* data) { printf("%d",  *(const int*)   data); }
void print_data_ptr     (const void* data) { printf("%p",  data); }
void print_data_nothing (const void* data) {}

void print_type_char        (void) { printf("char");          }
void print_type_short       (void) { printf("short");         }
void print_type_int         (void) { printf("int");           }
void print_type_int_p       (void) { printf("int*");          }
void print_type_void_p      (void) { printf("void*");         }
void print_type_void_f_void (void) { printf("void(*)(void)"); }


void print_data (const variant_t* var)
{
  var->print_data(var->data);
}

void print_type (const variant_t* var)
{
  var->print_type();
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "variant.h"

int main (void) 
{
  char c = 'A';
  short s = 3;
  int i = 5;
  int* iptr = &i;
  void* vptr= NULL;
  void (*fptr)(void) = NULL;

  variant_t var[] =
  {
    variant_init(c),
    variant_init(s),
    variant_init(i),
    variant_init(iptr),
    variant_init(vptr),
    variant_init(fptr)
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof var / sizeof *var; i++)
  {
    printf("Type: ");
    print_type(&var[i]);
    printf("\tData: ");
    print_data(&var[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Type: char      Data: A
Type: short     Data: 3
Type: int       Data: 5
Type: int*      Data: 000000000022FD98
Type: void*     Data: 000000000022FDA0
Type: void(*)(void)     Data:
```

Disadvantages with `_Generic` for this purpose is that it blocks us from using private encapsulation, since it has to be used as a macro in order to pass on type information.

On the other hand, the "variant" in this case has to be maintained for all new types one comes up with, so it isn't all that practical or generic.

Still these tricks are good to know for various similar purposes.